# python, saving changes made to an imported module

Tags: python, savechanges

I have a situation where users can pick another method from another clases and use it in thier own class using the .im_func.  i give an example below

```
import foo1
import foo2
foo1.ClassX.methodX = foo2.ClassX.methodX.im_func
```

Where methodX could be implemented differently in both modules.
When i instantiate the object say  `foo1.Class(), methodX from module`foo2` is used.

My problem is how to save the changes made maybe as foo3.py to a new source code file.

Comment: Why would you do this vs. subclassing and multiple inheritance?

Comment: The classes are the same but of different versions.

Comment: so you're dynamically mixing versions? Anyway, what you'll get is compiled objects which you can't easily reconvert into source code.

Comment: @keith, that is problem i am trying to solve!

Comment: That's the wrong problem to solve here. This would create a maintenance nightmare. Surely there is a better way...

Answer (score 0):

saving it as new py could be a problem but you can easily use serialization for it (pickle module)

see: http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

Comment: but the function is inside object and this can be serialized. Or I`m missing the point ?

Answer (score 0):

The source code can be retrieved with [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#retrieving-source-code) module. However, the problem with that is, that it's the original source code, not source code of dynamically modified object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [parser](http://docs.python.org/library/parser.html#module-parser) combined with the aforementioned [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) to do this?  In this situation it might be better to simply go with text processing rather than attempting to use imported modules.

EDIT: An example of using the parser to print the file:

```
with open('foo1.py','r') as fh:
    st = parser.suite(fh.read())
    src1 = parser.st2list(st)

with open('foo2.py','r') as fh:
    st = parser.suite(fh.read())
    src2 = parser.st2list(st)
```

You'd have to then do some tricky programming to merge the methods from the source code and write it to a file.  But then again I have the strange feeling I'm not quite understanding the question...

Comment: could u be having an example?